# Error while decoding camera stream video frame using FFMpeg iOS

Tags: c++, ios, ffmpeg, h.264, ip-camera

I have an app, In which I am decoding video frames coming from ip camera, but the method `avcodec_decode_video2(m_pCodecCtx, m_pFrame, &consumed_bytes, &avpkt);` present in `avcodec.h` generating bad_access, I can't figure out what is wrong.

This app was working fine with old libraries FFMpeg, but by apple policy, in order to publish app it support arm64, so I updated my libraries to support arm64 and after that this issue occurred.

**Here is the screenshot**

[image]

**While bad_access app is generating the following log:**

```
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 12 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] pps_id 417 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 3 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 32 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 6 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 32 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 3 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 32 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 2 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 2 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 2 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 2 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 2 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 32 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 3 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 2 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 2 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 2 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 2 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 2 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] pps_id 418 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] Partitioned H.264 support is incomplete
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 6 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 1 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] non-existing PPS 3 referenced
[h264 @ 0x1071400] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] slice type 10 too large at 0 0
[h264 @ 0x1071400] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] non-existing PPS 2 referenced
[h264 @ 0x1071400] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] slice type 29 too large at 0 0
[h264 @ 0x1071400] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 2 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x1071400] slice type 32 too large at 0 0
[h264 @ 0x1071400] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1071400] slice type 32 too large at 0 0
[h264 @ 0x1071400] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1071400] slice type 32 too large at 0 0
[h264 @ 0x1071400] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1071400] slice type 32 too large at 0 0
```

**Complete error log :** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Nh7ci6wLX0OVlxaXV4aGpJems/view?usp=sharing

**Crash Log :** http://crashes.to/s/6765d63b540

Note: If you need any thing else, please comment.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't appear to match the crash log.  The crash log looks like an issue dereferencing NULL.. Also it would be useful to know the parameter values.

Comment: what parameters you want to see. just tell me what you need.

Comment: The parameters passed to that method

Comment: let me updated crashlogs and parameters. please wait

Comment: @trojanfoe updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved my issue, The problem was with depreciated method `avcodec_alloc_frame()`.

I was using the following code in constructor

```
    m_pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(m_pCodec);
    if(m_pCodecCtx == NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"if(pCodecCtx == NULL)\n");
        return ;
    }  
   [g_Lock lock];
    //¥Úø™codec°£»Áπ˚¥Úø™≥…π¶µƒª∞£¨∑÷≈‰AVFrame£     
    if(avcodec_open2(m_pCodecCtx, m_pCodec, NULL) >= 0)     
    {     
        m_pFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();   /* Allocate video frame   */

    }
    [g_Lock unlock];
```

Then I eventually updated my header files, afterward I got warnings about depreciation of method `avcodec_alloc_frame()` so, I updated it to `av_frame_alloc()` and it worked flawlessly!